# adb.exe not responding.kill manually

Tags: android

I have just installed android studio. It is giving me the following error **"adb.exe not working"**. I tried to manually kill it but I was not able to do it, because it didn't show me in the task manager

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Wait more` And wait for a moment. It will start.

And if you want to kill the process, look under the `background processes` in Task manager. It should be there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`adb` is a `process`. So as @Nivedita mentioned, you won't it in `Applications or Apps`, but `Processes or Background processes`.

I have encountered this problem very often, especially while I was working with ADT-Bundle in Eclipse. If you are going to do it often, I suggest you to have `adb` in the PATH variable, that way you could execute commands via `Command Prompt`.

To kill ADB  :  `adb kill-server`
To start ADB :  `adb start-server`